# How to compare to optional model properties with XCTAssertEqual

Tags: ios, swift, xctest

Is there a better way to compare the values in my model object, than the following snippet which seems very verbose and it's only for one property?

**Model Object**

```
struct Address {

    static let kADDRESS1 = "address1"
    static let kADDRESS2 = "address2"
    static let kADDRESS3 = "address3"
    static let kCITY = "city"
    static let kSTATE = "state"
    static let kPOSTAL_CODE = "postalCode"

    var address1:String?,
    address2:String?,
    address3:String?,
    city:String?,
    state:String?,
    postalCode:String?

    init(address1: String?,
            address2: String?,
            address3: String?,
            city: String?,
            state: String?,
        postalCode: String?) {
            self.address1 = address1;
            self.address2 = address2;
            self.address3 = address3;
            self.city = city;
            self.state = state;
            self.postalCode = postalCode;

    }
    init(params:NSDictionary) {
        self.init(address1: params.objectForKey("address1") as String?,
            address2: params.objectForKey("address2") as String?,
            address3: params.objectForKey("address3") as String?,
            city: params.objectForKey("city") as String?,
            state: params.objectForKey("state") as String?,
            postalCode: params.objectForKey("state") as String?)
    }
}
```

**From test case**
   func testCreateAddress() {

```
let params:NSDictionary = [Address.kADDRESS1: "1 Main St.", Address.kADDRESS2: "Apt. 1", Address.kADDRESS3: "Box 1", Address.kCITY: "San Francisco", Address.kSTATE: "CA", Address.kPOSTAL_CODE: "7899"];

let address = Address(params:params);

if let param  = params[Address.kADDRESS1] as String? {
    if let property = address.address1 {
        XCTAssertEqual(property, param)
    }
    else {
        XCTFail("properties do not match")
    }
}
else {
    if let property = address.address1 {
        XCTFail("properties do not match")
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

I think you can assume a few things in your test:

1. `XCTAssertEqual` will let your test fail (with an appropriate error
   message) if the strings are not equal and thus you don't need any `XCTFail`
2. `params[Address.kADDRESS1]` is definitely set as you just defined it
   above

So I'd suggest to change your test to look like this:

```
let params:NSDictionary = [Address.kADDRESS1: "1 Main St.", Address.kADDRESS2: "Apt. 1", Address.kADDRESS3: "Box 1", Address.kCITY: "San Francisco", Address.kSTATE: "CA", Address.kPOSTAL_CODE: "7899"]

let address = Address(params:params)
XCTAssertNotNil(address.address1)
XCTAssertEqual(address.address1!, params[Address.kADDRESS1], "address1 should be set")
```

I admit that in case `address.adress1` is nil, you will get a runtime exception as the `XCTAssertEqual` will not be able to unwrap the variable but `XCTAssertNotNil` will fail beforehand so you know what's happening.

Comment: While in this test params[Address.kAddress] is not null, it will be in other tests, it which case I'll have to compare if they are both null, I'd eventually like to make this into function that I can call with any permutation of params

Answer (score 0):

I think I've found a more succinct way:

```
    if(address.address1? != nil && params[Address.kADDRESS1]? != nil) {
        XCTAssertEqual(address.address1!, params[Address.kADDRESS1]!)
    }
```

Comment: You need to give the test the opportunity to fail. This will just skip the test if one of the values is nil and you will never know from the tests alone. Also, you should unwrap the optionals in you invariant.